# MySQL Query - Rename data?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to set/rename data returned by a query, my query looks like:

```
userlevel   count
  1           5
  2           3
  3           11

SELECT USERLEVEL, COUNT(*) AS total FROM admin_xxx
GROUP BY USERLEVEL ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
where client = %CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%
```

(last line is WordPress related - wpdatatables placeholder)

I would like to rename 1 as Junior, rename 2 as Intermdiate and 3 as Senior.
I don't want to return the actual number.

So if data returned (Level) equals = 1 -> set as Junior.....
Count is fine.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have those levels stored in another table, that also contains the text/name? Then go look into JOINs. If not, you can use the [`ELT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt) function to achieve this for a static list of values.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(userLevel =1,'Junior',IF(userLevel =2,'Intermediate','Senior')) as levelname, ...
```

if you have more than a few levels, i suggest a [CASE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp) statment

Comment: ELT is fine as suggested above, but only if the numbers are incremental

Answer (score 0):

Use `CASE WHEN THEN`

```
SELECT

  CASE USERLEVEL
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Junior', 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Intermediate', 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Senior'
    ELSE 'Unknown'
  END CASE as userlevel,

  COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM admin_xxx
GROUP BY userlevel 
ORDER BY total;
```

Comment: can you group level1, level2 and level3 as "Junior" and level4.... up using CASE?

Comment: Yes, just define `WHEN..THEN`-s for Your cases and use `ELSE` for another rules

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN USERLEVEL=1 THEN "Junior"
WHEN USERLEVEL=2 THEN "Intermdiate"
WHEN USERLEVEL=3 THEN "Senior"
END as UserLevel
, COUNT(*) AS total FROM admin_xxx
GROUP BY USERLEVEL ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10
where client = %CURRENT_USER_LOGIN%
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.